# Were Shadrach, Meshach, and Abednego told that there would be no miracle?

Tags: miracle, prophecies, daniel-book-of

I've heard a story somewhere before that before Shadrach Meshach and Abednego got toasted (literally), they came to a prophet asking whether there will be a miracle or not. (I forget the prophet's name. Maybe it was Isaiah.) The prophet says that there will be no miracle, but God makes one anyway.

I've been trying to find the story using Google but can't find it. Where can I find it?

Comment: I did not recognize the names, so I looked it up. As per a quick Wikipedia search, I found that these people are also known as Chananiah, Mishael, and Azaria. You seem to be asking about when they were thrown into the furnace, which can be found in the beginning of the Book of Daniel. I seem to recall learning Midrashim addressing your question, but I don't remember them well enough to answer your question.

Comment: @Salmononius2 These are perfectly acceptable names to use to refer to them.

Comment: Sorry, it's sometimes hard to properly convey intent in a written statement. I didn't mean to sound like I was criticizing the names, but I assumed that others might also not recognize those versions of the names, so I brought up their arguably 'more common' names.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadrach,_Meshach,_and_Abednego Looks like Sadrach, Meshach, and Abednego is the more popular name and the bible actually uses that name. The wikipedia entry uses sadrach, meshach, and abednego instead of hananiah, misael, and azaria

Comment: @JimThio On a jewish website people are more likely to know the hebrew names. The popular and wikipedia uses are atributable to non jews beeing more numerous. Additionally the bible you are using is a translation, so its irelevant what names your copy of the bible has.

Answer (score 5):

From the plain reading of the text (Daniel 3:17-18), we see that they were unsure whether Hashem would save them.  In particular, they say (3:18) והן לא (and if [Hashem does] not
 [save us]).

In [Shir HaShirim Rabbah (on 7:8, על דעת ר׳ שמעון)](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/shir/7-2.htm), we see a midrash that relates how Chananiah, Mishael, and Azariah went to Ezekiel to ask whether Hashem would be with them if they gave up their lives instead of bowing to Nebuchadnezzar's idol.  Ezekiel tells him that Hashem is not with them (לא מתקיים עליכם).  Hence, it seems from this midrash that they thought they wouldn't be saved. The end of that midrash says that Hashem tells Ezekiel that of course He's with them, and in the end of course they're saved.

Comment: oh man, beat me by five minutes and got two upvotes already! shkoyach :)

Comment: And why Ezekiel told them that Hashem will not be with them? After all, Hashem does not save every would be martyrs right?

Comment: @JimThio Translation (from אישי התנ״ך) of the end of the midrash: "As soon as they left, the Holy One, Blessed is He, appeared to Ezekiel and said to him, 'Do you think I will not save them? Surely I will. But tell them nothing, so that they will go with simple faith, as it is written, (Prov. 10:9) He who goes with simple faith will go securely.'"

Comment: So God won't tell lie, but may deceive by silent.

Answer (score 5):

There is a tradition that these three people had asked Ezekiel whether they would be saved, and he responded in the negative. The story is referred to in [Zohar Toldos 142a](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9F&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%25D7%2596%25D7%2594%25D7%25A8_%25D7%2597%25D7%259C%25D7%25A7_%25D7%2590_%25D7%25A7%25D7%259E%25D7%2591_%25D7%2590&ei=KQ9tU_TJK5S-sQSX8oHABw&usg=AFQjCNHT26YAwaCYPqxZJ7FTvOs19aEeGQ&sig2=HKSe8P9_2vwzl-0gLsWZOA&bvm=bv.66111022,d.cWc) but discussed at length in Midrash Rabba Shir Hashirim (sometimes called Midrash Chazis) 7:13. There, a long discussion is recorded between these three would-be martyrs and the prophet Ezekiel about whether or not they should subject them selves to being burned.

This story (and its implications) is also mentioned in halakhic (legalistic) literature regarding the question of optional martyrdom. For example, see Shita Mekubetzes to Kesuvos 33, and the Merkeves Hamishna (Alfandari) and Avodas Hamelech to Rambam Hil. Yesodei HaTorah (5:1).

Answer (score 0):

@magicker72 and @Matt found the medrash that identifies Ezekiel as the prophet that they asked.  Since they answered the question, I am just going to expand on why it appears to be a "nevuah that was not carried out".

Note that he did not prophesy that they would not be saved but Ezekiel tells them that Hashem is not with them (לא מתקיים עליכם). However, on a hashkafa basis one cannot expect to be saved and must react as if he would not be saved through a miracle. The fact that they were saved does not invalidate that.

For someone to be worthy of a miracle and to be saved, he has to be willing to die and not expect a miracle. We have the principle "Ain Somchin al hanes" (do not rely on a miracle). Note that Rashi says that "they responded" (to Nevudchadnetzar) that they did not expect to be saved, not that they were told that they would not be saved.

> “You shall not desecrate My holy Name, rather I should be sanctified
> among the Children of Israel; I am Hashem Who sanctifies you.” Vayikra Emor 22:32
>
> You shall not desecrate – If a Jew is in a situation in which he is required to give up his life rather than desecrate G-d’s Name, he should do so without expectation of a miracle occurring to save his life. Rather he should act as Chananiah, Mishael, and Azariah did when threatened by Nevuchadnezzer, who wished to cast them into a fiery furnace unless they bowed to his statue. They responded that G-d was surely capable of saving them, but they didn't know if He would, and were prepared to sacrifice themselves regardless, rather than desecrate His Name. – Rashi

Another example is Avraham and his brother. Avraham was saved and his brother was not. There are commentators who say that Haran waited to see what happened to Avraham and when Avraham was saved he declared that he was ready to give up his life (without the expectation of being saved) for what Avraham had proved true. Haran was then thrown into the furnace and died.

Nachshon ben Aminadav jumped into the sea when Hashem told the Bnei Yisrael to enter it without the expectation of (he himself) being saved. If his death was required to save the rest of Bnei Yisrael, he was ready for it. Hashem then split the sea.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question...

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question... Acting as if one will not be saved doesn't preclude knowing that one will  be saved.

Comment: @DoubleAA If one "knows" or expects that he will be saved, he cannot act as if it does not matter if he is saved or not. A person's expectations will affect what he does in any case.

Comment: ???? That is simply false. People can choose to do whatever they want.

Comment: @DoubleAA but their expectations influence them. Expecting that you will be saved means that it is not really a test and that you are not really putting yourself in danger.

Comment: Who said it _had_ to be a "test"? Who said you had to "really put[] yourself in danger"? Somebody could be willing to die Al Kiddush Hashem even without ever doing so.

Comment: Actually this is what I really want to know. So don't expect a miracle. It's God's will. I didn't know that Haran is burned?

Comment: @DoubleAA If you are put in danger by the action of others, (as in this case or that of Avraham) then being willing to die, means acting properly.

Comment: @Jim Thio This is from the medrah about Haran dieing before his father. The commentators ask why this is explicitly mentioned in the Torah and give this as an explanation. Some say he waited to see what would happen to Avraham and them made his declaration and was not saved. Some say he did not expect to be saved and some say he did expect to be saved.

Comment: The story of Haran being burned is not in the torah. I am not even sure if Abraham is monotheistic. Gen 20:13 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elohim#Abraham.27s_.22the_gods_caused_me.22

Comment: @JimThio I did not say it was. I gave it as an example. The commentators who bring the story use it to exaplain why his deathe is meantioned in the way it was.

Comment: I see. Abraham uses elohim followed by plural verb when addressing abimelech. The most natural translation should be "the gods lead me here". As usual, that phrase is unnaturally translated. That would be another question.

Comment: @Jim Thio The references are a matter of making the plural as a matter of respect such as is done for the "royal We". An analogy would be the usage of the French tu and vous. In English we have dropped the singular "thou" for the plural "you" in all cases. There are also secular circumstances in which this is found such as referring to a slave's master which uses the pural form. This is a problem in translation with contexts, idioms, and implications that do not translate exactly. Note that the Names of Hashem use the plural form even though the meaning is singular.

Comment: the story of haran and abraham that is being burned. where does that story comes from?

Comment: @JimThio Bereishis Rabbah 38:23 and Targum Yonasan ben Uziel, Bereishis 11:28 [The Death of Haran. by Rav Zvi Belovski](http://kabbalistnyc.com/?p=664)

Answer (score -1):

See [Ezekiel 9:4-6](http://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.9.4?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)?  The young men, like the three you are talking about - plus Daniel, taken in the First Exile to Babylon, were divinely protected and could not be harmed.  They did not know that, however, but were simply willing to leave the outcome of their lives to their God.  Either way, He WOULD deliver them - in the flesh or in Paradise.